# Symfony2 app, MongoDB: Count all records matching criteria

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, mongodb-query

In my controller I'm fetching limited number of objects (for pagination) like this:

```
    $dm   = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb');
    $repo = $dm->getRepository('AcmeMyBundle:MyDocument');

    $criteria = array(
        'field1'    => 'value1',
        'field1'    => 'value1',
    );

    $logs = $repo->findBy(
        $criteria,                      /* criteria */
        array($field => $direction),    /* sort */
        $limit,                         /* limit */
        (($page-1)*$limit)?:null        /* skip */
    );
```

Now I like to get total number of records that meet the `$criteria`.

I was trying to count it like this:

```
$count = $repo->createQueryBuilder('MyDocument')
    ->count()->getQuery()->execute();
```

But it counts all records in collection. How can I apply `$criteria` to that counting query?

I need result as native `MongoDB` `db.MyDocument.find({'field2': "value1", 'field2': "value2"}).count()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done it like this:

```
    $countQuery = $repo
        ->createQueryBuilder('MyDocument')
        ->requireIndexes(false)
        ;

    foreach(array_filter($criteria) as $field=>$value){
        $countQuery->field($field)->equals($value);
    }

    $count = $countQuery->count()->getQuery()->execute();
```